# React + Next.js download a file from server to client

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im looking for a way to serve a PDF file so the users can download it by clicking on a button,Im using React and Next.js for SSR.

What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

placing the documents inside public folder and using the following a tag seems to work

```
 <a download href="filename.pdf" > Get file </a>
```

I dont know if this is an ideal solution because those files are occupying space in the server,I was thinking about using a cdn,or maybe upload it to some kind of storaging service